# Artifacts when changing background colour of JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, transparency, background-color, jtextarea

I'm having a problem when setting the background colour of a  JTextArea after I set its text. The code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea area;

    public Test() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(this.area = new JTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(new JButton(clickAction), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        this.pack();
        this.area.setText("this is just a test");
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    Action clickAction = new AbstractAction("Click") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            area.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 123, 138));
            // repaint();
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

If I click the button, the background of the JTextArea changes, but I also get some artifacts in the text area. The "repaint" seems to fix it, but in my application example, it doesn't help, so I was wondering whether there is a better solution to this.

[image: example image]

Comment: Please have a look at Rob Camick's blog on this: [backgrounds-with-transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/)

Comment: @EdStaub: My "answer" is only a a link and thus should be a only comment.

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing one text i think

```
Action clickAction = new AbstractAction("Click") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        area.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 123, 138));
        area.repaint();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using a partially transparent color for the component's background.  Try setting your background color's alpha channel value to 255 and see if the artifacts still show up.  The call to `repaint()` fixes the issue because it forces the underlying buffer to be filled with your background color prior to painting the text (I think).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with a project I worked on for school recently.  You have to call repaint on the frame too (so I changed the ActionListener to take a JFrame in the constructor).  I also rearranged the code to use the content pane of the JFrame.  This seems to work for me:

```
 public Test() {
    this.area = new JTextArea();

    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.getContentPane().add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JButton button = new JButton(new MyClickAction(this));
    button.setText("Click Me!");

    this.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));

    this.area.setText("this is just a test");

    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}

private class MyClickAction extends AbstractAction 
{
    private JFrame frame;

    public MyClickAction(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        area.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 123, 138));
        frame.repaint();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problems and resolved them by using the validate() method on the component in question.  So many things it could be... maybe I'll get slammed for this but - speaking as one who has just spent an entire year laboring with Swing - I say to you:  RUN!!  Swing is just about deprecated.

Learn JavaFx 2.0 and help bury Swing.